# Fast way to add elements in a numpy array based on indexes in another array

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a following problem:

I have two 1D arrays of the same length, for example:

```
data    = array([5, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1])
indexes = array([1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5])
```

I want to add elements from `data` that have the same value in the corresponding places in the `indexes` array, so in this example I want to get as the output:

```
expected_output = array([6, 3, 6, 6, 6, 3, 1])
```

I can compute this by:

```
lst = []
for i in indexes:
    lst.append(data[indexes == i].sum())
output = np.array(lst)
```

The problem is this implementation is slow. When the input arrays have lengths on the order of one million this can take 10 minutes. How can I do this faster?

**Additional information on my main problem**

In general my problem is a sub-problem of an actual problem I'm trying to solve, namely how to divide all columns in a scipy sparse matrix by the sum of the columns (and then also divide all rows by the sum of rows), something I would have done in Pandas as:

```
df.div(df.sum(axis=0), axis=1)
```

and

```
df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

But Pandas fails to handle the data sizes I'm working with. When I try to do the same thing using scipy csr_matrix I get division by 0 problems, because some rows and some columns have all zeros, but I guess I could get around that by setting certain values to 1 in the sum vectors. But the bigger problem is that code:

```
csr_arr / csr_arr.sum(axis=1)
```

results in

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.82 PiB for an array with shape (255999995, 999999) and data type int64
```

so the implementation tries to convert to a dense representation and this fails. I decided to implement this division by the sum vector entirely in the sparse representation, like so:

```
row_arr, col_arr = csr_arr.nonzero()
sum_col_lst = []
for i in row_arr:
    sum_col_lst.append(csr_arr.data[row_arr == i].sum())

sum_row_lst = []
for i in col_arr:
    sum_row_lst.append(csr_arr.data[col_arr == i].sum())

prob_a_given_b_data = csr_arr.data / np.array(sum_row_lst)
prob_b_given_a_data = csr_arr.data / np.array(sum_col_lst)

csr_prob_a_given_b = csr_matrix((prob_a_given_b_data, (row_arr, col_arr)), shape=shape)
csr_prob_b_given_a = csr_matrix((prob_b_given_a_data, (row_arr, col_arr)), shape=shape)
```

and this works fine, even for very large matrices (and I need to work with sparse matrices of shapes hundreds of millions times millions and holding millions of non-zero values) but like I said those `for` loops take a long time since nothing is vectorized there.

Comment: `_, i = np.unique(indexes, return_inverse=True); np.bincount(i, data)[i]` to avoid computing the same sum multiple times.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like the answer I was looking for and it is very fast. For 1 million records this runs in 0.3 s instead of the 10 minutes for the `for` loop. Please submit this as an answer so I can accept it.